# Woocommerce cart displays outdated prices

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm facing the following situation on a fresh WooCommerce installation.
Have added a custom field on product brands, to allow administrators set a discount on all products of a selected brand.

The discount displays nicely everywhere (category pages, custom loops, single page, variable products etc), but when a product is added to cart, its initial price is displayed instead at the totals section.

Have tried to hook on the `get_price()` - which calls the `get_prop()` - using `woocommerce_product_simple_get_regular_price` filter, but for some strange reason the filter doesn't get applied!

Already validated that the `context` parameter has a value of `view`, so the filter should be applied, but...

Initially thought this is a session/cache issue and tried incognito mode, other browsers, other devices etc, but that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Any thoughts on this? Thanks in advance

Using Wordpress 4.7.4 and WooCommerce 3.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo! Instead of using the `woocommerce_product_simple_get_regular_price` I had to use the `woocommerce_product_simple_get_price` filter.

Hope this helps someone

Comment: I have found the article about WooCommerce discount cart which describe how to get discount on total sales, orders, shipping cost and sales per item
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/woocommerce-discount-cart/